# Should I use Class, Struct or Dictionary for an object containing some simple config parameters?

Tags: swift

In an IOS project, I want the user to be able to config their UI.

The user will pick:

> "backgroundColor", "fontColor", "fontSize", "font", "lineSpace"

in *UIConfigViewController* and when user hit done, the result will be stored in an object and passed back into *ReadingViewController*.

Should I use `Struct`, `Class` or `Dictionary` for this result object?

Can I use the Struct like this?

Ended up using NSManagedObject

Comment: How will you store those properties? CoreData, NSUserDefaults? If using core data fore example, you might want to use a nsmanaged object directly.

Comment: @SwiftRabbit If I want to connect my app with an existing api which takes json, should I use NSUserDefaults or CoreData? Thank you!

Comment: @SwiftRabbit Thank you I ended up using NSManagedObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply implement `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults`, which is basically a dictionary for user settings.  The main advantage for that is it's designed to be accessible at the global scope so no need to pass the object around.